# Getting exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element:

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

DOM structure

abc.test
                    
           
I am getting below mentioned error. Tried via cssSelector as well.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"li > div"}
(Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element

Comment: DOM structure <li class="pull-right">
<a uib-popover-template="'app/layout/rightMenu.html'" popover-trigger="'click  focus'" popover-placement="bottom-right" popover-is-open="rightmenuPopoverOpen" class="ng-binding">
     abc.test
                    </a><div uib-popover-template-popup="" uib-title="" content-exp="contentExp()" origin-scope="origScope" class="popover ng-scope ng-isolate-scope bottom fade bottom-right in" tooltip-animation-class="fade" uib-tooltip-classes="" ng-class="{ in: isOpen }" style="top: 50px; left: -31px;"><div class="arrow" style="top: -11px; right: 6px;"></div>

Comment: you want to click?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question the generic solution is :

you can wait for visiblity of element:

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("Locator")));
```

or wait for presence of element

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("Locator")));
```

or use executeScript() method to scroll the element

```
WebElement elemLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elemLocator);
```

Comment: @ iamsankalp89 Above mentioned solution is not working . Getting error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/nav/div/ul[2]/li/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element

Comment: can u add a screenshot which element you want to locate

Comment: i need to click on abc.test button

Comment: DOM structure <li class="pull-right"> <a uib-popover-template="'app/layout/rightMenu.html'" popover-trigger="'click focus'" popover-placement="bottom-right" popover-is-open="rightmenuPopoverOpen" class="ng-binding"> abc.test </a><div uib-popover-template-popup="" uib-title="" content-exp="contentExp()" origin-scope="origScope" class="popover ng-scope ng-isolate-scope bottom fade bottom-right in" tooltip-animation-class="fade" uib-tooltip-classes="" ng-class="{ in: isOpen }" style="top: 50px; left: -31px;"><div class="arrow" style="top: -11px; right: 6px;"></div> –

Comment: use like this //*[normalize-space(text())='abc.test'], it may be possible your element in the Frame